# Tags geradas dinamicamente com ajax não são enxergadas por jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou gerando uma tabela dinâmica através de AJAX que, em um dos TDS há um link.

```html
<a href="#modalInserirDescontoCB" class="modal-trigger id_aluno">104490</a>
```

**O link deve realizar duas tarefas:**

1. Abrir um modal que contém um formulário (classe `modal-trigger` do *materializecss* é responsável);
2. Preencher um dos campos do formulário com o texto do link clicado.

**O código da segunda tarefa:**

```js
$('.id_aluno').click(function () {
    $('#campo_aluno').val(this.text);
});
```

Onde `#campo_aluno` é um `input` do modal.

**O AJAX que faz a requisição:**

```js
tabela = $('#tabela-resultado-alunos');
filtro = $('#aluno').val();

if (filtro == '') {
    alert('Preencha o campo.');
    return false;
}

$.ajax({
    url: path + 'cb/lista-alunos',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        get: filtro,
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    beforeSend: function () {
        tabela.html('Carregando...');
    },
    success: function (retorno) {
        tabela.remove('.bloco');

        // Atribui o retorno HTML para a div correspondente             
        if (retorno == 0) {
            $(tabela).html('Deu ruim');
        } else {
            $(tabela).html(retorno);
        }
    },
    error: function (erro, er) {                 
        $(tabela).html('Erro ' + erro.status + ' - ' + erro.statusText + '</br> Tipo: ' + er + '</p>');
    }
});
```

**A função PHP que retorna a tabela HTML:**

```
$output = <<<HTML
    <table class="striped bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NOME</th>
                <th>CPF</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
HTML;

foreach ($alunos as $a) {
    $output .= <<<HTML
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#modalInserirDescontoCB" style="cursor: pointer" title="Preencher número de aluno com esse valor" class="modal-trigger id_aluno">{$a->pf_id}</a></td>
            <td>{$a->nome}</td>
            <td>{$a->cpf}</td>
        </tr>
HTML;
}

$output .= '</tr></tbody></table>';

return $output;
```

Quando clico em um dos links gerado, nenhuma das funções são executadas.
 Também tentei um simples `$('.id_aluno').click(function(){console.log('funcionou')});` e nada acontece, **como se o conteúdo gerado não fosse enxergado pelo *jquery***.

Comment: Coloque o trecho de código de geração dessas tags, por favor.

Comment: Vou complementar a pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode-se usar o méthod `.on`, sucessor do `.delegate`, visto que o elemento foi adicionado ao DOM depois de ele ter sido inicialmente montado e interpretado pelo script. Tente algo como:

```
$(document).on('click', '.id_aluno', function(){     
    $('#campo_aluno').val(this.text);
    $('#meuModal').openModal(); 
});
```

Comment: Assim funcionou. Minha dúvida agora é como abrir o modal do materializecss através do jquery, uma vez que o exemplo mencionado na própria documentação não funciona.

Comment: Caso o modal abra corretamente, provavelmente poderei dar como solucionado.

Comment: Testei aqui, na verdade para abri-lo seria algo como $('#meuModal').openModal();
Se puder, por favor altere sua resposta, pois estarei marcando a mesma como correta.
Alias, muito obrigado!

Comment: pode acessar esse chat?
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52133/jquery

Answer (score 3):

Thiago, creio que o erro esteja no

```
$('.id_aluno').click(function () {
    $('#campo_aluno').val(this.text);
});
```

pois o evento é atrelado no elemento que já está criado, e como vc mencionou, é criado outros elementos dinamicamente.

A solução seria você atrelar o evento ao jquery on.

```
$(".id_aluno").on("click", function(){
    $('#campo_aluno').val(this.text);
});
```

Comment: Mesma situação que comentei com o @MagicHat aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178306/tags-geradas-dinamicamente-com-ajax-n%C3%A3o-s%C3%A3o-enxergadas-por-jquery#comment368416_178308

Answer (score 2):

Troque esse trecho :

```
$('.id_aluno').click(function () {
    $('#campo_aluno').val(this.text);
});
```

por esse:

```
$('.modal-trigger.id_aluno').click(function () {
    $('#campo_aluno').val(this.text);
});
```

Comment: Nada acontece, nem mesmo um erro.
Já com o link estático continua funcionando, inclusive da forma que mencionou. Lembrando que isso só acontece com os links gerados dinamicamente.

Comment: Brother num tô entendendo, esse gerado dinamicamente, se der coloca esse código que gera o código do modal... vamos vasculhar

Comment: Completei a pergunta.